# How can I continuously replay audio from an AudioInputStream?

Tags: java, audio, streaming

I have a AudioInputStream which comes from a network source. It continously streams audio from an Arduino. How can I replay this continously? My current approach is just reading it to a Stream, but this will stop after the given length of 10000 frames.

```
AudioInputStream ais = new AudioInputStream(client.getInputStream(), new AudioFormat(AudioFormat.Encoding.PCM_UNSIGNED, 4000, 8, 1, 1, 4000, false), 10000);

DataLine.Info nfo = new DataLine.Info(Clip.class, ais.getFormat());
Clip clip = (Clip)AudioSystem.getLine(nfo);

clip.open(ais);
clip.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `new AudioInputStream()`, try using `AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream()`.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/AudioSystem.html#getAudioInputStream%28javax.sound.sampled.AudioFormat,%20javax.sound.sampled.AudioInputStream%29

Comment: I don't know how this could solve my problem? I can't even tell that function what AudioFormat my stream has. My current problem is not that I can't replay audio, but instead that I don't know how to continuously stream it.

Comment: There's another function in that class where you can specify the target output format.  I have updated my answer.

Comment: That other function wants me to give it a AudioInputStream to convert it to another Format (!?). And the other function doesn't work either way, because it needs mark and reset ability, to auto detect format, which my stream doesn't support (cause it is a network stream).

Answer (score 0):

OK I didn't recognize SourceDataLine. With a SourceDataLine you can just write your Data from the stream directly to the AudioLine which allows you to stream Audio over Network.

```
InputStream ins = client.getInputStream();

DataLine.Info nfo = new DataLine.Info(SourceDataLine.class, new AudioFormat(AudioFormat.Encoding.PCM_UNSIGNED, 5000, 8, 1, 1, 5000, false));
SourceDataLine line = (SourceDataLine)AudioSystem.getLine(nfo);

byte[] buffer = new byte[512];

line.open();
line.start();

while(true) {
   int read = ins.read(buffer);
   line.write(buffer, 0, read);
}
```